# Using the DTM tool to load a synchronous third party javascript before DOM ready

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am looking to use the DTM tool to load a synchronous third party javascript before DOM ready and not on page load. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Adobe DTM has four main [Load Order Types](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/load_order.html) for controlling when a page rule is evaluated, two of which occur before DOM ready: "Top of Page" and "Bottom of Page".

Within the rule, for 3rd party script tags, you can choose various options for loading the tag sequentially (synchronously): "Sequential HTML", "Sequential Javascript Local", and "Sequential Javascript Global".

**Note:** DTM makes use `document.write` to accomplish this functionality, which [may be blocked by users who use Chrome on slow internet connections](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/c_chrome_2G.html).